# Viewing sheet tabs - Excel starter 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel Starter 2010, the sheet tabs aren't displayed down the bottom. There is an option in File->Options->Advanced->Display Options->Show sheet tabs, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Are they supported?

Comment: [Yes they are](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rqOyk.png).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the split bar between the scroll bar and the sheet tabs isn't all the way to the left blocking any sheet tabs from showing. Shown below is normal, split bar all the way to the left and sheet tabs turned off.

[image: Normal] 
[image: Split bar all the way to left]
[image: Show sheet tabs turned off]